# Customize handleOptionClick in renderOption of MUI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So this is my code:

```
{/* Search suggestions Autocomplete Field */}
      {suggestionsFetched && <Autocomplete
          disablePortal
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={searchSuggestions?.salons.map((salon) => ({
                    type:'salon',
                    id:salon.id,
                    label:salon.name.toLowerCase()
                  }))
                    .concat(searchSuggestions?.services.map((service) => ({
                      type:'service',
                      id:service.id,
                      label:service.name.value.toLowerCase()
                    })))}
          renderOption={(props, option) => {
            return (
              <li 
                {...props}
                key={option.id}
              >
                <span style={{
                  fontWeight:'bolder',
                  textTransform:'capitalize'
                }}>{option.type}:</span>
                {"\u00A0"}
                <span style={{
                  textTransform:'capitalize'
                }}>{option.label}</span>
              </li>
            );
          }}
          popupIcon={<Search color='secondary' />}
          sx={{
              width: '100%',
              [`& .${autocompleteClasses.popupIndicator}`]: {
                transform: "none"
              }
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField placeholder="Search" {...params} />}
      />}
```

The data I am displaying are of 2 types: salon and service. I want the default behaviour of selecting the option and displaying it. But I also want to set a state value to the type. The purpose of this is to direct to specific route based on the type.
Now since I know that the onClick function is set in the props, how do I override it. This is what I did and it did not work:

```
{suggestionsFetched && <Autocomplete
          disablePortal
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={searchSuggestions?.salons.map((salon) => ({
                    type:'salon',
                    id:salon.id,
                    label:salon.name.toLowerCase()
                  }))
                    .concat(searchSuggestions?.services.map((service) => ({
                      type:'service',
                      id:service.id,
                      label:service.name.value.toLowerCase()
                    })))}
          renderOption={(props, option) => {
            return (
              <li 
                {...props}
                onClick={()=>{
                  setSearchRoute(option.type)
                  props.onClick()
                }}
                key={option.id}
              >
                <span style={{
                  fontWeight:'bolder',
                  textTransform:'capitalize'
                }}>{option.type}:</span>
                {"\u00A0"}
                <span style={{
                  textTransform:'capitalize'
                }}>{option.label}</span>
              </li>
            );
          }}
          popupIcon={<Search color='secondary' />}
          sx={{
              width: '100%',
              [`& .${autocompleteClasses.popupIndicator}`]: {
                transform: "none"
              }
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField placeholder="Search" {...params} />}
      />}
```

In the above code, I tried to reset the onClick prop, set my state and then call the default onClick function. But it threw this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'currentTarget')

How to resolve this and override default onClick prop? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution. I just needed to write an onChange function

```
value={selectedSuggestion}
onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    setSearchRoute(newValue.type)
    setSelectedSuggestion(newValue);
}}
```

The **newValue** argument is actually the object passed in the options props.
This is so obvious and I don't know why it took me so long to figure out